# Default Size of Integral Literal Constant

Tags: c

```
void foo(void* arg)
{

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  foo((void*)1);
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any standard that compilers are to meet that defines the default size (as in bytes) of the integral literal constant passed to foo?

Comment: You're passing a void pointer in this case, so it's sizeof(void *).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing an integer literal constant to `foo`; you're passing a `void *`, which is defined to have size `sizeof(void *)`.

More generally, if you do pass an integer constant expression as an argument to a function, then there are two possibilities:

- you have a prototype for the function; in this case, the integer constant expression is converted to the declared type of the corresponding argument before the function call.
- you do not have a prototype for the function, or it is a variadic argument; in this case, the argument will be passed as an `int`.  (**caf** correctly notes that this does not apply to integer constant expressions with higher rank than `int`, like `35U` or `-17L`).

Comment: Your second bullet point does not apply to all integer constant expressions - for example, the constant `1L` is an integer constant expression, but would be passed to an unprototyped function as a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is only size of the argument that function is expecting and it is obviously a size of a pointer (4 on i386, or 8 on x86_64 etc). Also, see [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) wiki.